# SQLAlchemy's automap_base creates bad collections for one-to-many tables

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy to recreate tables in an existing SQL Server database. The usual declarative base wasn't working out so I am trying to use the automap base.

My DB has a table called 'orders' and I am trying to query the data:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model.metadata.reflect(bind=db.engine)

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(db.engine, reflect=True)

db.session.query(Base.classes.orders).all()
```

However, an ArgumentError is thrown:

> ArgumentError: orders.orders and back-reference
>   orders.orders_collection are both of the same
>   direction symbol('ONETOMANY').  Did you mean to set remote_side on the
>   many-to-one side ?

The SQLAlchemy doc tells me that the latter orders.orders_collection is automatically created. What could I do to make sure the creation of this collection doesn't lead to this ArgumentError?

Comment: I'd need to see more information about your database structure to know what's going on.  For instance the table definitions of the tables involved with the primary and foreign keys, minimum.

Comment: Other than that, your code seems solid, works for me (I don't have a db structure like yours I'm sure).

Comment: Maybe you did something like having a foreign key on both tables pointing to the primary key on the other.  If that's the case, make sure to put a table in the middle of the two, with two columns, each being the primary key of one of the tables.