# Have not been able thus far to get Flask-MySQL reflection working

Tags: python, mysql, reflection, flask, sqlalchemy

I've been searching StackOverflow questions and reading SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy docs, and have still not figured out how to get reflection working (still new to SQLAlchemy).

When I try to map the table using the engine, I get the error "sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|User|user could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'user'".
In spite of that, user has column 'id' as a primary key in the database.  I'm not sure if there's something else I need to do here first.  I had thought that if I could reflect, it would automatically give my User model class properties named after the database columns, and I wouldn't have to define them manually.

Here is my code that I've cobbled together so far:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://" + dbUser + ":" + dbPass + "@" + dbAddress + ":3306/" + dbName

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
engine = db.engine
meta = db.metadata
```

Now with that, I know that db will give me a good database session.  I'm not sure yet about what I'm doing wrong with engine and meta.  I've seen engine being used to create the context differently, but I think I'm creating that with this line (from above):

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Here's the place where I'm trying to reflect a model class:

```
class User(db.Model):
     try:
         self = db.Model.metadata.tables('user', metadata)
         #self = Tadb.Model.metadata.tables('user', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, extend_existing=True)
         #Table('user', metadata, autoload_with=engine, extend_existing=True)
         #self = Table('user', meta, autoload_with=engine, extend_existing=True)
         #self.metadata.reflect(extend_existing=True, only=['user'])
    except Exception as e:
         print("In init User(): failed to map table user - " + str(e))
```

I get the mapper error on this line (from above):

```
self = db.Model.metadata.tables('user', metadata)
```

I've tried the other lines as well, but it doesn't seem to know what Table is...I have Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2.

Am I making any obvious mistakes here?

Comment: I may have found something at this link:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html

I included these lines into my code:

"from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base",

"Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)",

And then I changed the user's model class from User(db.model) to be:

"User(Base.classes.address)"

It's compiling successfully now, still need to test.

Comment: not sure this syntax will work, mostly if you refer to address, use `User = Base.classes.user` instead

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting User has no attribute query now when I try to do:  users = User.query.filter_by(username=username).all()

Comment: I started using the Python command line to type in the code and see output at all steps + do more random printing, and printing the engine shows it's just the full URL for the database connection, and meta shows it's not bound.  So I still need to connect and bind.  Think I'm getting somewhere.

Comment: I found a question with someone asking for help on binding to multiple databases, and it included a short set of code which has gotten automapping working for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064015/sqlalchemys-automap-base-creates-bad-collections-for-one-to-many-tables
I will have to add it to my code, get rid of all the commented out lines, and answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for your help PRMoureu.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by reflecting the `id` field (or its real name in the database) and all the fields you will need in your code :

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

Comment: OK, thank you, I actually commented those lines out / didn't include them in my question.  Am I right in understanding that I should be able to have the properties automapped?

Answer (score 2):

This has taken me several days of effort, reading over 30 StackOverflow Q/As and going down quite a few rabbit holes in the SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation, trying and discarding quite a few code fragments.  This is what I've pieced together.  Note:  this is with Flask-MySQL version 2.3.2.

I thought it was rather unusual that Flask-SQLAlchemy provides an engine and metadata after app initialization, but the documentation on their page has them importing different engine and metadata modules from SQLAlchemy.
Not only that, but they are also importing a separate session engine, and I have just used the Flask initialized database context to get a session, and it works.

Not only that, but this does what 99% of the Q/As here on StackOverflow state is impossible with Flask-SQLAlchemy - automapping / reflection of the database tables.  That is, I do not have to declare properties on the classes at all, those come from the database directly.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
#The file I am importing below is named config and is in the same folder as app.py.
#It has json formatted text and looks like this (without the '#' signs, and remove the <> signs that surround
#the places you need to insert the db address, username, password, and database name (instance name - 
#database servers can have multiple databases on them, each one is called an instance / has a different name))
#{
#"dbAddress" = "<some IP or URL to your database server>",
#"dbName" = "<database name>",
#"dbUser" = "<database user name>",
#"dbPass" = "<dbPass>"
#}
with open('config') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    dbAddress = data["dbAddress"]
    dbName = data["dbName"]
    dbUser = data["dbUser"]
    dbPass = data["dbPass"]
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://" + dbUser + ":" + dbPass + "@" + dbAddress + ":3306/" + dbName
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = True


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model.metadata.reflect(bind=db.engine)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    def __init__(self, db, username, password, email):
        try:
            self = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username==username) #.one()
        except Exception as e:
            print("In init User():  Failed to load an existing user into the model for user '" + username + "' " + str(e))
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.emailAddress=emailAddress
        try:
            db.session.add(self)
            db.session.commit()
            print("In init User():  Inserted or updated user '" + username + "'")
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print("In init User(): insert or update exception on user '" + username + "': " + str(e))
            return False


    def delete(db, userid):
        try:
            self = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).one()
            db.session.delete(self)
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print("In User.delete(): failed to delete userid '" + self.id + "', username '" + self.username + "': " + str(e))


    def getAllUsers(db):
        return db.session.query(User).all()


    #Setting this to blank would "logout" the user.
    #This is because csrf_protect prevents POST requests from going through other
    #than login and signup.
    def updateSessionToken(db, userid, token):
        try:
            self = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).one()
            self.sessionToken = token
            db.session.add(self)
            db.session.commit()
            print("In User.updateSessionToken(): Successfully updated the token for userid '" + userid + "'.")
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print("In User.updateSessionToken() failed to update token: " + str(e))
            return False


    def checkSessionToken(db, userid, givenToken):
        try:
            user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).one()
        except Exception as e:
            print("In checkSessionToken(): issue looking up userid: " + userid + ": " + str(e))
        if user:
            if user.sessionToken == givenToken:
                print("In User.checkSessionToken():  token match confirmed for userid '" + user.id + "', username '" + user.username + "'.")
                return True
            else:
                print("In checkSessionToken() - token and given token do not match")
        else:
            print("In checkSessionToken() - user by given id '" + userid + "' not found.")
        return False
```

Comment: Working repo with full setup instructions (including dependencies export and command to create a conda environment from it with all required dependencies) here:  https://github.com/DiginessForever/flicklistBlog